# Question on two formulas of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, inertial-frames

I am reading Jackson's $Classical$ $Electrodynamics$ and there are two forumlas which cause some problems for me. What happens is that if I combine those formulas in a certain way, I can deduce some absurd results. Let me explain:

The formulas in question are:
$$\textbf{E}(\textbf{x}) = k\int \rho(\textbf{x}')\frac{\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|^3} d^3 x'$$
and
$$\textbf{E}(\textbf{x}) = -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(\textbf{x}')}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|} d^3 x'$$
where the first is (1.5) and the second is (1.15), both in chapter 1. $\textbf{E}$ is the electric field, $\rho$ is the charge density and $k$ is a constant depending on the system of units.

Here is my (probably wrong) reasoning: Assume that $\rho$ is radially symmetric and assume that $A$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix. The first equation gives us
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(A\textbf{x}) &= k\int \rho(\textbf{x}')\frac{A\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'}{|A\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|^3} d^3 x'=k\int \rho(A\textbf{x}')\frac{A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}'}{|A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}'|^3} d^3 x' \\
&= k\int \rho(\textbf{x}')\frac{A(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}')}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|^3} d^3 x' = A k\int \rho(\textbf{x}')\frac{\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|^3} d^3 x' = A\textbf{E}(\textbf{x})
\end{align*}
where I used transformation of the integral by an orthogonal matrix in the first line and radial symmetry of $\rho$ and $|\cdot|$ in the second. So, $\textbf{E}(A\textbf{x})=A\textbf{E}(\textbf{x})$.

Now, from the second equation of Jackson, I can do this:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(A\textbf{x}) &= -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(\textbf{x}')}{|A\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|} d^3 x' = -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(A\textbf{x}')}{|A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}'|}  d^3 x' \\
&= -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(\textbf{x}')}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|} d^3 x' = \textbf{E}(\textbf{x})
\end{align*}
where I used similar calculations as above.

The conclusion would be
$$A\textbf{E}(\textbf{x})=\textbf{E}(A\textbf{x})=\textbf{E}(\textbf{x}).$$
Since the orthogonal matrix $A$ was arbitrary, this holds for all orthogonal $A$ and hence, always $\textbf{E}(\textbf{x})=0$ in case $\rho$ is radially symmetric. But isn't this absurd and totally wrong? Where is the mistake in my argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mauntain out if a molehill. Remember that in
$$
\nabla \left\{\int d^3x'\frac{\rho(x')}{|x-x'|}\right\}
$$
the $\nabla$ is $\nabla_x$ a derivative wrt to $x$ not wrt $x'$. All you need therefore is to differentiate under the integral sign using
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{|x-x'|}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}}\\
= -\frac{x-x'}{((x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2)^{3/2}}
$$
and similarly for $y$ and $z$.

The prblem in your conclusion  is that have forgotten to include the $A$ in the $\nabla_x$ which is not equal to $\nabla_{(Ax)}$.

Comment: many thanks! just forgot this part about $\nabla_x \neq \nabla_{(Ax)}$

Answer (score 3):

The mistake appears to be in the step
$$ -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(A\textbf{x}')}{|A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}'|}  d^3 x' = -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(\textbf{x}')}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|} d^3 x'. $$
Let $f(\textbf{x})=1/|\textbf{x}|.$ We can write
$$ \textbf{E}(A\textbf x) = -k\nabla\int \frac{\rho(A\textbf{x}')}{|A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}'|}  d^3 x' = -k\int \rho(A\textbf{x}')\nabla[f(A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}')]  d^3 x' \\
= -kA\int \rho(A\textbf{x}')(\nabla f)(A\textbf{x}-A\textbf{x}')  d^3 x'
= -kA\int \rho(\textbf{x}')(\nabla f)(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}')  d^3 x'  \\
= -kA\nabla\int \frac{\rho(\textbf{x}')}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|}  d^3 x'=A\textbf E(\textbf x)$$
where the third equation uses the chain rule for differentiation, and the fourth uses the radial symmetry of $\rho$ and $\nabla f$.

Comment: Thank you too! Now I see my problem!